# MIT opencourseware - stuck on a basic issue, credit card minimum payment over a year calculation

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Basically I'm pretty stuck on this issue, I've linked the question below, it's part 'b' I'm stuck on, or the second question in the document:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00sc-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-spring-2011/unit-1/lecture-4-machine-interpretation-of-a-program/MIT6_00SCS11_ps1.pdf

If I'm honest it's just got to the point where I'm totally confused! I've put my code below:

```
balance = float(raw_input('Vot is the outstanding balance? '))
InrAn = float(raw_input('Vot is the annual interest rate as a decimal? '))
month = 1
monthPay = 10
monthInr = InrAn/12.0
newBalance = balance

while balance > 0:
    newBalance = newBalance * (1 + monthInr) - monthPay
    month +=1
    if month > 12:
        month = 1
        newBalance = balance
        monthPay += 10
```

This does essentially nothing, I know, and it's not yet complete. If I add a 'print month' statement it just seems to show that the code just goes up to 12, then starts at 1 again. Any tips/prods in the right direction?

Comment: You should update your question to reflect what exactly you are trying to achieve (as I imagine not many people will be motivated to read through the linked assignment). I for one am unsure what exactly your problem here is. do you want to break from the loop once your `month` reaches 12?

Answer (score 0):

```
monthly_payment = 10.0
while True:
    current_balance = start_balance

    for month in range(1, 13):
        current_balance = current_balance * (1. + monthly_rate) - monthly_payment
        current_balance = round(current_balance, 2)
        if current_balance <= 0.0:
            break

    if current_balance <= 0.0:
        print("RESULT")
        print("Monthly payment to pay off debt in 1 year: {}".format(int(monthly_payment)))
        print("Number of months needed: {}".format(month))
        print("Balance: {:0.2f}".format(current_balance))
        break

    monthly_payment += 10.0
```